# Error: Main malloc.cp en array dinamico de enteros

Tags: c++

Estoy simulando un Vector por medio de un *array* dinámico de enteros, el *append* consiste en agregar un numero indicado a aquella lista siendo manejado por un *pivot* que funcionara como el tamaño que expanderá el arreglo y asi mismo su posición. Pasa que al agregar mas de 6 números con el *append*, me salta el siguiente error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual no ocurre si agrego menos de 6 elementos con el *append*. ¿A que se debe?

El código es este:

```
class Vector{
public:
      int pivot;
      int*list;

      Vector();
      ~Vector();
      void append(int number);
      int getNum(int position);
};

Vector::Vector(){
      this->pivot = 0;
      this->list = new int[pivot];
}

Vector::~Vector(){
      delete[] list;
}

void Vector::append(int number){
      this->list[pivot] = number;
      this->pivot++;
}

int Vector::getNum(int position){
      return this->list[position];
}

int main() {
       Vector enteros;

       enteros.append(1);
       enteros.append(2);
       enteros.append(3);
       enteros.append(4);
       enteros.append(5);
       enteros.append(6);
       enteros.append(7);

       cout<<"numero: "<<enteros.getNum(5)<<endl;

       return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Miremos tu constructor:

```
Vector::Vector(){
    this->pivot = 0;
    this->list = new int[pivot];
}
```

Con ese código reservas espacio para **0 elementos**.
Buscando un poco, encontramos [C++ new int[0] — will it allocate memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1087066/12529507)

> Then the value of the expression in a direct-new-declarator is zero, the allocation function is called to allocate an array with no elements.
> ...
> The effect of dereferencing a pointer returned as a request for zero size is undefined.
> ...
> Even if the size of the space requested [by new] is zero, the request can fail.
> ...
> The intent is to have operator new() implementable by calling malloc() or calloc(), so the rules are substantially the same. C++ differs from C in requiring a zero request to return a non-null pointer

En traducción libre:

> Si el valor del número de *bytes* a reservar es `0`, la función de reserva de memoria es llamada para reservar 0 elementos.
> ...
> Desreferenciar un puntero obtenido al reservar 0 *bytes* es un **comportamiento indefinido**.
> ...
> Si el espacio a reservar es 0 *bytes*, la llamada a `new[]` puede fallar.
> ...
> La idea es poder utilizar `malloc( )` o `calloc( )` para implementar el `new`, por lo que las reglas son similares. Sin embargo, C++ requiere que una reserva de 0 *bytes* retorne un puntero no nulo.

Así pues, tu problema es sencillamente que estás incurriendo en **comportamiento indefinido** al realizar el `new[]` en tu constructor.

> ... en array dinámico de enteros.

Bueno, eso de *dinámico* ... **nunca cambias ese tamaño inicial**, así que tienes problemas adicionales.

Una posible solución sería:

```
#include  <algorithm>

Vector::Vector( ) {
    pivot = 1;
    list = new int[pivot];
}

void Vector::append( int number ) {
    list[pivot - 1] = number;
    pivot++;
    int *tmp = new int[pivot];
    std::copy( list, list + pivot - 1, tmp );
    delete[] list;
    list = tmp;
}
```

<sub>**Nota**: ese código es meramente ilustrativo. La eficiencia del mismo es malísima.</sub>