# Problema con almacenamiento de enteros en un vector puntero en la posición #9 en C++

Tags: c++, string, while, punteros, números-enteros

He diseñado un programa el cual almacene los números en un vector, y detendrá dicho almacenamiento cuando el usuario escriba la palabra "fin", la cuestión está en que no tengo idea el por qué en la posición #9 de mi código, retorna un número basura, incluso le pedí ayuda a mi profesor y no tiene idea el por qué.

Este es mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
 int* vector = new int[0];
 string numero="";
 int tamanio = 0;
 char verificador = 'b';

 while(verificador != 'a'){
   getline(cin,numero); // Siempre el componente #9 genera un número basura, y no entiendo el por qué y cómo quitarlo o evitar que eso pase
   if(numero == "fin") verificador = 'a';
   else{
     int numeroInt = atoi(numero.c_str());
     vector[tamanio] = numeroInt;
     tamanio++;
   }
 }

 for(int i=0; i<tamanio; i++){
   cout<<vector[i]<<" ";
 }

 delete [] vector;
 return 0;
}
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Se ve que estáis los 2 en el mismo colegio o algo: [Error: Main malloc.cp en array dinamico de enteros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/407405/149531)

Comment: No, no es el mismo error, imprime común y corriente, el problema está que al imprimir, siempre en al posición #9 retorna un número basura (de 5 o 6 dígitos) que nada tienen que ver con el número que insertaría

Comment: ¿¿ Que no es el mismo error ?? ¿¿ En serio ?? Yo llevo gafas, y aún así lo veo **muy claramente**: `int* vector = new int[0];`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo raro es que te funcione algo en ese programa, está mal desde la primera instrucción de `main`:

```
int* vector = new int[0];
```

En esa línea solicitas memoria para almacenar **CERO** enteros. ¿Cuántos enteros caben en un vector de cero elementos?: Ninguno.

Eso significa que cada vez que accedes a `vector` estás accediendo fuera de la memoria solicitada, lo cuál es [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) y hará que el programa se comporte de manera errática: podría funcionar, podría fallar, podría funcionar o fallar aleatoriamente o podría invocar [demonios que saldrían disparados de tus fosas nasales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

Si quieres un contenedor de datos que crezca dinámicamente, usa una `std::list` o un `std::vector`, [según se ajuste a tus necesidades](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/54180/2742).

Si quitamos todo lo innecesario de tu código, corregimos los errores y lo reescribimos siguiendo las recomendaciones de C++ moderno, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    list<int> datos;
    string dato{};

    while (getline(cin, dato) && dato != "fin")
    {
        stringstream dd{dato};
        int valor;

        if (dd >> valor)
            datos.push_back(valor);
        else
            cout << dato << " no es un numero\n";
    }

    for (const auto &valor : datos)
        cout << valor << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU/bTsMwDH2Ov8IUaeskQHQTEmKlX4KEQpJ10VKnahJ4mPbtxWmYgKc4x@dmNY73yknq5/nWknJJG2ytD3EycujgF2PEUv8XcTbEf4yrCCxFHKSlegNnECmwEEkOJoxSGQxR7wFElrfM7FDL6MMeRIlYvudLpnwdrTNY9yY6S6ZWlu6W7QZXq2XAm1esDpaqDQhO@nEoPVDrc@awkxC50ad0fsq2wh6w1hq7rmAsFmIp8TCmcHz/kOpUl03WGhdMZiifIrZtCea3QvJoAiZCSoOZ/BtVzL9wwsFPWCtPIaJMzF4tbvhSTs15V7Oy4GGN69xtMjFNhI97uMxzAw1sYQdPIHs5Mm7hGZodbBvgo@Eb)</kbd>.